# Material cardView background color for child element

Tags: android, android-cardview, materialcardview

I am using material cardView in my application. Everything is running smoothly. I have set a background color for my cardView and child element individually. It is fine if I have one card with one child element. But I might have to add multiple cards with multiple child elements. My question is

1. Can we make child element inherit the background color of the parent ?
2. Or I have to set everything indidvidually ?
3. Is it possible to give just one background color for entire cardView including child elements ?

   ```
   <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
       android:id="@+id/cardView2"
       android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"   
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Grey">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textViewCardTown2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:backgroundTint="@color/LightGrey"
       android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

   </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
   ```

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Is it possible to set once background color for entire material cardView  even to the child elements

Comment: can't you just make your child elements background color transparent?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But since the elements are on top. The cardView color is not visible.

Comment: so set your child background trasparent #0000000

Comment: If you make the card grey, and the children have NO background color (transparent background color), it should work.

Comment: I agree but it didnt work. You have to explicitly set the background to transparent to child

Comment: @AnasMehar I set backgroundTint in my child to transparent. It worked dude. Thank you. If you post an answer it will be helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the background color of the child layout to transparent.

Set:

`android:background="00000000";`

Comment: I added backgroundTint to transparent, though.